# Semantic UI Tablesort not working in Meteor

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface, meteor, semantic-ui

I'm trying to make a sortable table with Semantic UI via Meteor in a Blaze Template but the sorting function will not work

```
<template name="Home_Page">
  <div class="ui container">
    {{#if Template.subscriptionsReady}}
      <table style="margin-top: 20px" class="ui sortable celled table">
        <thead>
        <tr>
          <th class="descending">First</th>
          <th>Last</th>
          <th>Address</th>
          <th>Telephone</th>
          <th>Email</th>
          <th>Edit</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        {{#each contact in contactsList}}
          <tr>
            <td>{{contact.first}}</td>
            <td>{{contact.last}}</td>
            <td>{{contact.address}}</td>
            <td>{{contact.telephone}}</td>
            <td>{{contact.email}}</td>
            <td><a href="{{pathFor 'Edit_Contact_Page' _id=contact._id}}">Edit</a></td>
          </tr>
        {{/each}}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    {{else}}
      {{> Loading}}
    {{/if}}
    <script src="https://semantic-ui.com/javascript/library/tablesort.min.js">
    </script>
    <script>
      $('.sortable.table').tablesort();
    </script>
  </div>
</template>
```

The table appears appropriately, and the celled table component works but the sortable part doesn't

I've tried to implement this without the usage of Meteor which worked as intended

```
  <div class="ui container">
      <table style="margin-top: 20px" class="ui sortable celled table">
        <thead>
        <tr>
          <th class="descending">First</th>
          <th>Last</th>
          <th>Address</th>
          <th>Telephone</th>
          <th>Email</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>Bob</td>
            <td>Burt</td>
            <td>123</td>
            <td>456</td>
            <td>incredible@gmail.com</td>
          </tr>
                    <tr>
            <td>Cob</td>
            <td>Aurt</td>
            <td>123</td>
            <td>456</td>
            <td>incredible@gmail.com</td>
          </tr>
                    <tr>
            <td>Dob</td>
            <td>Durt</td>
            <td>123</td>
            <td>456</td>
            <td>incredible@gmail.com</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    <script>
      $('.sortable.table').tablesort();
    </script>
  </div>
```

Code for the non-Meteor version can be found in this JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/seanytak/0wyrxqt0/

Are there additional steps to implement the same behavior in Meteor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

3rd party libraries like this require the DOM to have been rendered when they are initialized.  Your `table` with class `sortable` has not been rendered when you call `$('.sortable.table').tablesort();`

To do this, you need to move `$('.sortable.table').tablesort();` into your templates `onRendered` callback, with an `autorun` to handle the wait for the subscription data to arrive, and to reinitialize the component when new data is received and the template is rerendered.

[Link to blaze docs](http://blazejs.org/guide/reusable-components.html#Use-onRendered-for-3rd-party-libraries)

This is sortable behaviour is trivial to create in Meteor without using 3rd party libraries though, using something like this:

```
import { Template } from 'meteor/templating';
import { ReactiveVar } from 'meteor/reactive-var';
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';

import './main.html';

Template.Home_Page.helpers({
  contactsList() {
    var data =  [
      {first: 'Bob', last: 'Dole', address: '123', telephone: '456', email: 'incredible@gmail.com' },
      {first: 'Fred', last: 'Dagg', address: '123', telephone: '456', email: 'incredible@gmail.com' },
      {first: 'Sam', last: 'Black', address: '123', telephone: '456', email: 'incredible@gmail.com' },
      {first: 'Frank', last: 'Smigh', address: '123', telephone: '456', email: 'incredible@gmail.com' },
    ];
    var sortedData = _.sortBy(data,
                              function(x){
                                  return x[Template.instance().sortBy.get()];
                              });
    if(Template.instance().sortOrder.get() == -1){
        sortedData = sortedData.reverse();
    }
    return sortedData;
  }
});

Template.Home_Page.onCreated(function() {
  this.sortOrder = new ReactiveVar(1);
  this.sortBy = new ReactiveVar('first');
});

Template.Home_Page.events({
  "click th":  function(event, template){
    headerClicked = _.find(
            event.currentTarget.classList,
            function(x){ return x.startsWith('js-');}
          ).slice(3);
    if( headerClicked == template.sortBy.get()){
      template.sortOrder.set(template.sortOrder.get() * -1);
    } else {
      template.sortBy.set(headerClicked);
      template.sortOrder.set(1);
    }
  }
});
```

and adding the following classes to your table header:

```
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th class="js-first">First</th>
    <th class='js-last'>Last</th>
    <th class='js-address'>Address</th>
    <th class='js-telephone'>Telephone</th>
    <th class='js-email'>Email</th>
    <th class='js-no-sort'>Edit</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
```

If the data is coming from Mongo, your `contactsList` helper would look something like:

```
Template.Home_Page.helpers({
  contactsList() {
    return Contacts.find({}, { sort: { Template.instance().sortBy.get() : 
                                       Template.instance().sortOrder.get() 
                                     }  });
  }
})
```